# Появляется ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, html

**javaScript**

```
function myBoi2() {
        var x = document.getElementById('Button_${i}')
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
      if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="Button_1" class="video-container"><iframe src="cilka" width="640" height="390" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>

<button class="video-button" onclick="myBoi2()">Тыц</button>
```

**Появляется ошибка:** *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null*

Comment: `x` у вас равен `null`.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков А как исправить?

Comment: Имейте в виду: `'Button_${i}'` — с обычными кавычками, считается обычной строкой, без какого-либо особого значения. `\`Button_${i}\`` — а внутри обратных кавычек `${ выражение }` имеет особое значение, позволяет вставить туда переменные или значения других выражений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверно как-то так:

```js
function myBoi2() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++ ){
        var x = document.getElementById("Button_"+(i + 1));
        if (x.style.display === 'none') {
            x.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            x.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="video-button" onclick="myBoi2()">Тыц</button>

<div id="Button_1" class="video-container" style="background: red;"><iframe src="cilka" width="640" height="390" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Но вы вообще не описали свою проблему, так что первое что пришло в голову.

Comment: Я делал множественный id, что бы можно было присваивать к разным дивам Button_1, Button_2, Button_3 и тд. Но после моих попыток, функция перестала работать

Comment: @A.D ну так и делайте только в цикле `i < 1` меняйте на соответственное кол-во дивов с таким `id`.

Comment: Спасибо большое